# Writing Russian text to txt file

Tags: character-encoding, applescript

I am trying to write some Russian text, or Cyrillic text, to a .txt file. I can successfully do so, but when I open the file all that is written in place of the text are a bunch of question marks. I was thinking it was an encoding problem but couldn't find anything in that area to help. I have written a little script that demonstrates the issue.

```
do shell script "> $HOME/Desktop/Russian\\ Text.txt"
set text_path to ((path to home folder) & "Desktop:Russian Text.txt" as string) as alias

set write_text to "Привет"

tell application "Finder"
    write write_text to text_path
    set read_text to text of (read text_path)
end tell
```

If anyone has any ideas as to why this is happening please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: What are you opening the file with?  Sounds like an issue with what's displaying the file to me.  It isn't detecting the character set, and is substituting question marks for characters it can't display.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't answer your question. You do have lots of applescript coding issues in your code but none of them are causing your problem. Applescript handles non-ascii text fine for me. I write in Danish some times and it works. However when I tried my script using Russian I got the same results as you. I can't explain why. Just so you can see the proper syntax for reading and writing a file here's my code. Note that I do not use the Finder to perform those tasks and also note how I set the path for the output file...

```
set outpath to (path to desktop as text) & "danish.txt"
set theText to "primær"

-- write the file
set openFile to open for access file outpath with write permission
write theText to openFile
close access openFile

-- read the file
set readText to read file outpath
```

UPDATE: I found an answer to your problem. It seems that if you write the utf-16 byte order mark (BOM) to the file then it works properly for Russian. As such I made two handlers so you can read and write these files...

```
set filePath to (path to desktop as text) & "russian.txt"
set theText to "Привет"

write_UnicodeWithBOM(filePath, theText, true)
read_UnicodeWithBOM(filePath)

on write_UnicodeWithBOM(filePath, theText)
    try
        set openFile to open for access file (filePath as text) with write permission
        write (ASCII character 254) & (ASCII character 255) to openFile starting at 0
        write theText to openFile starting at eof as Unicode text
    end try
    try
        close access openFile
    end try
end write_UnicodeWithBOM

on read_UnicodeWithBOM(filePath)
    read file (filePath as text) as Unicode text
end read_UnicodeWithBOM
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked like a charm. Thank you too for showing me the proper syntax. It's hard to know if you are getting it write when you learn from here and there. Thanks again.